# Update value from table column based on the value from another column

Tags: mysql

I have the table: countries and columns Country and Status
I wish to update only the values from the Status column based on a value from the Country column. SMTH like this

```
update ban_country_ip set
checkbox = 0
where country_name = United States
```

This syntax doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update countries
set `status`= 0
where country_name = 'United States'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update countries set
Status = 0
where Country = 'United States'
```